# Romans 11:32 according to Calvinist?

Tags: exegesis, reformed-theology, romans

> Romans 11:32
>    For God has bound **everyone** over to disobedience so that
>   he may have mercy on them all

Is the "everyone" including Adam and Eve before they are created ?

Comment: When one arrives at conclusions that are clearly illogical ('Adam and Eve before they were created') then one has to stop and consider that one's reasoning must - it really must - be flawed.

Comment: Nigel, my question appear as based on **Calvinist teaching itself which is clearly illogical**  ---> God predestined everyone before Adam and Eve created where one of the verse Calvinist use to prove is : _God loved Jacob hated Esau before the twins were born or had done anything good or bad_  while the verse is specific to an individual.

Comment: A question is a question, not a conclusion. The conclusion is in two options : God has bound everyone over to disobedience after the creation OR before the creation. Since I don't know which one is the Calvinist view, that's why I ask.

Comment: Neither scripture nor Calvin make any statements about mankind before it is created. It would be illogical to do so.

Comment: Nigel, I agree with you. So then there is no such thing "Unconditional Election" (???) : _Unconditional election (also known as unconditional grace) is a Reformed doctrine relating to Predestination that describes the actions and motives of God in eternity past, **before he created the world**_

Comment: Election is a matter of the Father and the Son. Thus it is an eternal matter. And it is a matter of God's foreknowledge. Election does not concern the first humanity.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand _"it is a matter of God's foreknowledge"_ , Nigel. Because what I know from the internet is : _Election Is Not Based on God's Foreknowledge_.

Comment: I find it best to receive Gospel doctrine from the word of God, holy scripture, myself. Whom he did foreknow, them did God predestinate, and whom he did predestinate them he also called, and whom he called them he also justified; and whom he justified them he also glorified.  Romans 8:29,30.

Comment: Actually I do agree on what you've said, Nigel. I don't understand why Calvinist try hard by playing words in order that Romans 8:29,30 can be concluded : _"therefore, Election/Predestination is not based on God's foreknowledge"_.

Comment: In the large context: Rom. 9:1 -11: 35, "everyone" refers  in restrict sense "the Jews and Gentiles."  Your question: "everyone" including Adam and Eve "before they are created ?" should be taken out, for you trying to insinuate those" un-biblical teachings"  into the forum.

Comment: @karma I believe strict Calvinist teaching sees "choosing" to respond to the Gospel as a "work" and so election according to foreknowledge would mean that God foreknew a human work and therefore elects/saves based on human works.

Comment: @NigelJ - Dear Nigel, you said "Neither scripture nor Calvin make any statements about mankind before it is created. It would be illogical to do so." - In view of Ephesians 1:4 - "According as he hath chosen us in him before the foundation of the world" - I don't know what you mean.  Please explain, thanks.

Comment: @AndrewShanks The scripture makes statements about _God and His purposes_ prior to creation. Ephesians 1:4 refers to the elect as in Christ. It does not refer to their coming to light (in the first creation) as children of Adam. I stand by what I said.

Comment: @NigelJ - "It does not refer to their coming to light (in the first creation) as children of Adam." - Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: @AndrewShanks Our first existence (our first being) is in Adam, by creation. Our re-birth is of Spirit, in conjunction with repentance and faith. The election of God (before the foundation of the world) is a matter, within Deity, of foreknowledge, viewing His people as _in Christ_ . They are chosen _in Christ_. . . . . .  Not _in Adam_. They are redeemed _out of_ Adam. And born again _in Spirit_ and _into Christ, in Spirit_.

Comment: @NigelJ - I'm sorry Nigel.  I simply do not understand what you mean.  You started with "Neither scripture nor Calvin make any statements about mankind before it is created".  What you have now written seems to have no bearing on whether that sentence is true or false.  I cannot make _any_ sense of what you are asserting or have any idea of the significance of what you are saying.  Can you please try one more time?  Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewShanks   I shall leave it there. My books are freely available [on my website](https://belmontpublications.co.uk/books/) but I cannot think of any one in particular that covers this subject in depth. I have said all that I would wish to. I cannot make it any clearer. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, Romans chapters 8-11 need to be taken as a whole and, if 1-11 can be taken that way it is even better.  Lone verses picked out of 9-11 are difficult to properly exegete.  I am pilfering the clue given in @Sam's comment to OP in order to construct an answer:

> In the large context: Rom. 9:1 -11: 35, "everyone" refers in restrict sense "the Jews and Gentiles."

The overarching thing that Paul is doing in Romans ch. 9-11 is 1) describing the special position of Israel in God's redemptive plan:

> Who are Israelites; to whom pertaineth the adoption, and the glory, and the covenants, and the giving of the law, and the service of God, and the promises; 
> Whose are the fathers, and of whom as concerning the flesh Christ came, who is over all, God blessed for ever. Amen. - Romans 9:4-5

2. Explaining how natural descent within Israel does not automatically guarantee promise:

> Not as though the word of God hath taken none effect. For they are not all Israel, which are of Israel: Neither, because they are the seed of Abraham, are they all children: but, In Isaac shall thy seed be called. That is, They which are the children of the flesh, these are not the children of God: but the children of the promise are counted for the seed. - Romans 9:6-8

And 3) how those who are called, according to promise are from both Jew and Gentile:

> Even us, whom he hath called, not of the Jews only, but also of the Gentiles? - Romans 9:24

Here it must be remembered that Paul has already laid out how the entire process of man's redemption, of which 'calling' is a part, begins with God's foreknowledge.  Many theologians of many different stripes have attached limitation of scope or meaning here but the Scripture does no such thing.  He declares the end from the beginning, we are told ([Isaiah 46:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2046%3A9-10&version=KJV)) and that, without qualification:

> For whom he did foreknow, he also did predestinate to be conformed to the image of his Son, that he might be the firstborn among many brethren. Moreover whom he did predestinate, them he also called: and whom he called, them he also justified: and whom he justified, them he also glorified. - Romans 8:29-30

This whole process wherein God has offered salvation freely, by grace through faith, and has foreknown who will call on the name of the Lord in response to this offer is available to "all", meaning both Jews and Gentiles:

> For there is no difference between the Jew and the Greek: for the same Lord over all is rich unto all that call upon him. For whosoever shall call upon the name of the Lord shall be saved. - Romans 10:12-13

Chapter 11 then starts with a question:  Based on the disobedience of Israel outlined in chapter 10 and the offer of salvation to the Gentiles, has God utterly cast Israel aside?  Of course not, says Paul, and his proof is that he, himself, is an Israelite and he has been saved:

> I say then, Hath God cast away his people? God forbid. For I also am an Israelite, of the seed of Abraham, of the tribe of Benjamin. God hath not cast away his people which he foreknew. - Romans 11:1-2a

Israel (natural) has not attained the election of grace (Romans 11:5-7) because, as we have seen, election is according to God's foreknowledge and not natural descent or national affiliation.  There are individual Jews who are a part of this 'remnant' (Romans 11:5) and in the Apostle's illustration they are the natural branches of the olive tree; the true, spiritual Israel; the children of Abraham by faith and heirs of the promise.  Into this 'olive tree' the called Gentiles are grafted in:

> For if thou wert cut out of the olive tree which is wild by nature, and wert graffed contrary to nature into a good olive tree: how much more shall these, which be the natural branches, be graffed into their own olive tree? For I would not, brethren, that ye should be ignorant of this mystery, lest ye should be wise in your own conceits; that blindness in part is happened to Israel, until the fulness of the Gentiles be come in.- Romans 11:24-25

By the time we get to the verses in question it needs to be remembered that the entire context thus far has revolved around how both Jew and Gentile have been and are being called unto salvation and shown mercy:

> For as ye in times past have not believed God, yet have now obtained mercy through their unbelief: Even so have these also now not believed, that through your mercy they also may obtain mercy. For God hath concluded them **all** in unbelief, that he might have mercy upon **all**. - Romans 11:30-32

The 'all' in view here is inclusive of Jews and Gentiles.  All (both groups) are shut together or included within unbelief so that all (both groups) may obtain mercy.

It is a mistake to try and force 'all' in these verses to speak in any way about each individual person or eternity past and God's intentions prior to creation other than the fact that election is according to foreknowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It was always God's plan, before the creation of the world, that all should sin against Him.  God is completely outside of time, it makes no sense to speak of things He planned before the creation and things planned after creation.  He has an eternal plan, and it has always existed since before the foundation of the world.

Of course, the "all" includes Adam and Eve and everyone else.

The reason given in the verse is so that God's grace can be displayed.

The grace is not given savingly to all, but all receive food and common blessings which they do not deserve.

The plan was God's plan, the blame for the sin is entirely ours.

Comment: Where do you find any scripture which supports the words contained in your first sentence ?

Comment: Romans 11:32, and in addition it is plain because everyone sinning is what has happened.  Are you saying that anything can happen outside God's will??  The hairs of your head are all counted, not a bird falls to the ground but it is the will of God.

Comment: He works all things after (or in accordance with) the counsel of his own will.. Ephesians 1:11.

Comment: That refers to God's own, independent, works. You are attributing sin to God, by saying that he planned that others should work sin against him.

Comment: @NigelJ the aim of men when they sin is evil, but God's design in man's sin is good, and for good purposes, He brings good out of man's rebellion and sin. James 1:13-14

Comment: Andrew, your answer is logical to me. Before the creation, God has bound everyone (including Adam and Eve) over to disobedience. IF not (and if it turn out Adam and Eve always obedience to God), then how God show mercy to Adam or Eve ? But if the answer is like this, then it doesn't need : _IF later on Adam/Eve disobedience THEN their generation will be born with Original Sin_.

Comment: @karma - if we believe only as far as our logic allows we are not going to get very far.  We simply cannot understand all about our infinite God.  God allows men to do evil: men intends evil but Godallows it for good purposes (Genesis 50:20, Acts 2:23)

Comment: Andrew, you wrote _"God allows men to do evil"_. Yes of course, because before the creation God has bound everyone over to disobedience. _"God allows it for good purposes_".... Yes, so that he may have mercy on them all. I would be glad if you can provide some quotes about this from a Reformed Church's father. Thank you Andrew.

Comment: @karma you said, *"because before the creation God has bound everyone over to disobedience."* Where in Romans 11 do you see that God has bound everyone over to disobedience "before creation"?

Comment: @MilesFett - Everything God plans is before the creation because God is outside of time.  If he plans something, then it is planned before the creation of the world.  If he chose us in him (Christ) before the foundation of the world, then there was a need to choose us in him, and that need was because we were bound over to disobedience.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the Scripture itself according to Romans 11:30-32

> <sup>**30**</sup> For as ye in times past have not believed God, yet have now obtained mercy through their unbelief: <sup>**31**</sup> Even so have these also now not believed, that through your mercy they also may obtain mercy. <sup>**32**</sup> For God hath concluded them all in unbelief, that he might have mercy upon all.

It is clearly stated that it is about the mercy of God. The key word is "mercy"; the mercy of the father to his son for the father is looking forward to the possibility of what may happen to his child. There is no such mercy you can think of if he sees his child with safer consequences.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. if I use Calvinist point of view, the sentence "_Yet now obtained mercy_" ---> in my understanding in the Calvinist pov ... that sentence is meant for the elect. The word : "ye", "their", "they", "all" ---> all refers to the elect. Assumed that Adam is the elect (Eve not), then it is Adam who will obtain the mercy, not Eve. Please correct me if I'm wrong.