# What do Calvinists teach about the Election of mankind? Is it before or after the Creation?

Tags: reformed-theology, predestination

From this [link](http://www.reformedtheology.ca/calvin.html):

> Calvin also reminds us that Paul states that the love God had for us
>   **before the creation** of the world had always been founded in Christ

From this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination):

> Calvinists believe that God picked those who he will save and bring
>   with him to Heaven **before the world was created**

From this [link](https://www.monergism.com/election-and-reprobation):

> Election is an act of God **before creation**

From this [link](https://www.monergism.com/election-and-reprobation):

> Reprobation is the sovereign decision of God **before creation**

---

From the sentences of the quotes above lead me to think that *Calvinist teach that the U (from Unconditional Election) is **before the creation***

but because in my [other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/73939/romans-1132-according-to-calvinist), there is a comment like this :
*Neither scripture nor Calvin make any statements about mankind before it is created. It would be illogical to do so.*

That's why I ask the question.

Comment: I think you've got your answer there, four quotes from mostly reputable Reformed sources, vs one quote from a single user on this site. It would be better to just ask NigelJ what he means - it's not very clear and does indeed seem out of step with everything else you'd see about the Reformed doctrine of election.

Comment: @curiousdannii My profile has my website on it and my website has a (business) email address. Anyone can ask me anything which they wish to clarify. No problem. Election is a matter of the Father and the Son, eternally. And election is not a matter of the first humanity.

Comment: @NigelJ Yeah that sounds more typical. I did expect that this was all a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Since virtually it's formation as a school of thought, Calvinism has disagreed about *the logical order of God's divine decrees*. Generally there have been **two** schools with the minority (5% according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_order_of_God%27s_decrees)) espousing the **pre-lapsarian** (lit. pre-fall) view that God elects to save and condemn *prior* to even create or allow sin. The majority view is the **post-lapsarian** (lit. after-fall) perspective which holds that Gods election to save and condemn follows the creation and sin of humanity.

Note that given the *determinism* of the Calvinist view of the world, and the *a-temporal* nature of God, it is, strictly speaking, improper to think of time *before* creation but these have been the commonly espoused views about the *logical* order in which God's commands about how the world would be made, occurred. This means in a temporal sense God elected *before* creating, but disagreement exists about whether he logically *decreed* election before or after *decreeing* creation and the fall.

**This is why the majority of reformed theologians and statements of faith can simultaneously claim that God elected to salvation and punishment (temporally) before creating even while almost none of them have been pre-lapsarian. Therefore, the [majority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_order_of_God%27s_decrees) have held that at the very least election is *logically subsequent* to human sin, even while God's plan was established before the *act* of salvation.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ninthamigo. I just don't understand this : _post-lapsarian (lit. after-fall) perspective which holds that Gods election to save and condemn follows the creation and sin of humanity_. Because I think this view doesn't show  "before creation". That's why I ask "before the actual do the creation" how is the chronological sense.  (continue)

Comment: Between : (A) determine who will be in heaven who will be in hell first - then create the plan on how is the process ---> where the plan is create and make the fall (B) determine all will be in hell first - then create the plan on how is the process ---> where the plan is : create and make the fall, then elect some of them who are in hell. Point-A is "before the creation" in a logical sense. Point-B is "after the creation" in a logical sense. Both point-A and B is before the actual doing the creation.

Comment: Point-A is a kind of the story of the potter. Point-B, for illustration : create all vessels which are going to be thrown to garbage, then from all those ugly vessels some are remade to be used as a decoration.

Comment: I think you understand, although the wikipedia page I cited has a great (colored!) graph that helps too. Yes, the post-lapsarian view does NOT teach election before creation in the logical sequence (although in God's omniscience election is already KNOWN). It teaches God decreed to create and to elect only subsequent to the fall. Pre-lapsarianism says God's election comes before even his decree to create.

Comment: You wrote "_Pre-lapsarianism says God's election comes before even his decree to create_". I think this show God doesn't "look to the future". While the Post-lapsarian show that God "look to the future".

Comment: To me,  in Prelaps : there is no external factor which causing God to plan thing. Whatever external factor, some who are to be in hell and some who are to be in heaven already determined at first. While in PostLaps, there is an external factor which causing God to plan a salvation - the fall.

Answer (score 2):

In the 1689 Baptist Confession of Faith, a historic Calvinistic faith confession that is a revision of the Westminster confession and used as a confession of faith by many reformed calvinist church today, state in Chapter 3 (Of God's Decree), Paragraph 5:

> Those of mankind that are predestinated to life, God, **before the foundation of the world was laid**, according to His eternal and immutable purpose, and the secret counsel and good pleasure of His will, hath chosen in Christ unto everlasting glory, out of His mere free grace and love,<sup>11</sup> without any other thing in the creature as a condition or cause moving Him thereunto.<sup>12</sup>
>
> 11 Eph. 1:4, 9, 11; Rom. 8:30; 2 Tim. 1:9; I Thess. 5:9
>
> 12 Rom. 9:13,16; Eph. 2:5,12

So for your question *What do Calvinists teach about the Election of mankind? Is it before or after the Creation?*
Mankind was elected for salvation before the creation

Comment: Thanks for the answer wildmangrove. You wrote : Mankind was elected for salvation before the creation. So, to be precise, do you mean : _Mankind was elected for salvation before the **actual doing** creation_ ?